# I need to compare two lists, index by index, and count the matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

First of all, I'm in my second week of learning python, so I'm a complete newbie, and am learning for fun and hobby, and by my own.

I'm making a small program to evaluate N multiple choices answers given by students.

It will generate 2 lists from user inputs, the first list will consist of the students answers, and the second, the correct answers.

So, first, I take an integer input telling the program how many questions will be evaluated, then it prompts the user to give the student answers, followed by the correct answers.

I need the program to evaluate if the answers are correct. As of now, I can only make the program compare the lists without regarding the index position, which is adamant in the program, since question 1 is different from question 2, and the answer will change.

This is what I've worked out so far in order to take the inputs correctly:

```
quest = int(input())
score = 0
stud = []
prof = []

for i in range(quest):
    ans = input()
    stud.append(ans)

for i in range(quest):
    gab = input()
    prof.append(gab)
```

So, no I have the list stud, containing the student answers, and the list prof, containing the correct answers, and need to compare both, index by index, to analise weather that particular index matches in both lists, and return me the number of times it matches.

I've thought about creating a third list with the indexes of the matches, and resolving the score with an len() function in this third list, but I can't think of how to compare the lists.

Comment: But aren't the indexes the same as `range(quest)` that you used to iterate before? So, you don't need a third list.

Comment: Do you know how to index a list and how to compare two values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in a generator expression:

```
sum(1 for i, j in zip(stud, prof) if i == j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like this?

```
for i in range(quest):
    if stud[i] == prof[i]:
        score += 1
```

Comment: the indentation isn't correct

Comment: Yes, he could. He could also create a list with Booleans for each question (which could be of use later if he want's to give a complete feedback to the student). But we try not to give a chunk of code without context when people ask for [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Better to help them solve the issue themselves.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the answer proposed by Hugh works and is more efficient than this one.

If you also want a list that indicates which answers are correct and which are not, you can also do this:

```
stud = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b']
prof = ['a', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'b']
nb_of_questions = len(stud)
correct = [0]*nb_of_questions

for i in range(nb_of_questions):
    if stud[i] == prof[i]:
        correct[i] = 1
grade = sum(correct)

print('correct answers:', correct)
print('grade:', grade)
```

Which returns:

```
correct answers: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
grade: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to create a list with indexes since you already have them in `range(quest)`. You have used them already.

But you could generate a new list with the comparisons:

```
results = []
for i in range(quest):
    results.append(stud[i] == prof[i])
```

or, more elegantly, you can use *list comprehension*:

```
results = [stud[i] == prof[i] for i in range(quest)]
```

This is going to generate a list of Booleans, e.g. `[True, True, False, False]`, and then you can add them. Python will convert True to 1 and False to 0, this is called *type conversion*.

```
grade = sum(results)
```

The advantage is that you get the list with the result for each question if, for example, you want later to tell the student in which questions he failed.

Comment: it is faster to use ```[1 for i in range(quest) if stud[i] == prof[i]]```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! The bolean subset is what I was trying to get. You explained it in a great way, thanks!

Comment: if you want to keep where the answers are different, ```[1 if stud[i] == prof[i] else 0 for i in range(quest)]``` is also faster

Comment: A multiple choice with 5000 questions??? Your professor really hates you. Now seriously: sometimes you may want to opt for less efficient code if it's more readable or you can reuse it. In this case, having the Booleans for each answer could be a bonus.

Comment: BTW, are you sure evaluating conditionals and acting in function of them is faster than, well, just evaluating them? I haven't tested your claim, but it seems counterintuitive.

Comment: yes I've timed it - if that's the case then use my 2nd comment as this gives that. the 5000 was just to increase the time to get more precise timings. It is faster because you don't have to do a type conversion every time in the sum, and the 1st is faster still because the list you're summing over is shorter

Comment: I'll trust you. But because of the application scenario (unlikely more than 20 questions), I would still prefer code that can be read closer to "natural" language.